# Saving data with jQuery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to have an alert whenever people start typing in the text box. It will return "Data Saved: " + my msg that's in the test.php folder.

```
$("#textbox").on('change keyup paste', function() {

           $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  url: "test.php",
                  data: { content: $("#textbox").val() }
                })
                  .done(function( msg ) {
                    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                  });
    });
```

I've tried changing "method" to "type". 
Using .serialize(). 
Using success: function

I'm not sure what the problem is. Thank you!

Edit: 
Added an error code. So far no error messages on console for this.

```
             $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  url: "test.php",
                  data: { content: $("#textbox").val() }
                })

              error: function (request, error) {
                alert("An error occurred");
               },

                success: function (response) {
              if (response == 'OK') {
                $("#diary").val()
               } else {
                alert("An error occurred");


                  }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the javascript console?

Comment: first thing check whether its hitting server. secondly write .fail method which will help u to identify whats the bug..   $.ajax({ }).done().fail(function(data){ })

Comment: It says this with the line error of ajax: Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.<anonymous> (loggedinpage.php:92)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)

Comment: @krishnar yes i did a previous code to alert when something is typed and it's working. I've so far added an error code and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment you are getting the following error:

> $.ajax is not a function at HTMLTextAreaElement. (loggedinpage.php:92) at HTMLTextAreaElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3) at HTMLTextAreaElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)

The error is telling you that the code cannot find the $.ajax() function anywhere in order to execute it.

At the same time, the message gives away the fact that you are using jQuery Slim. This cut-down version of the library does not include the $.ajax() function, among other things. You need to use the full version of jQuery.

Details in the latest (or any recent) release notes (in the "Slim build" section): https://blog.jquery.com/2017/03/20/jquery-3-2-1-now-available/

As a side note, I'm surprised that you want to show an alert every single time a user types a character into the textbox. I predict that this will quickly get very annoying for users. Maybe just showing a message inside a div nearby (which doesn't steal the focus and stop them typing) would be better. I'd also question whether it's really necessary to save the data to to the server every time a character is entered? If the user types quite a lot it will trigger off dozens of ajax requests. Your inclusion of the "keyup" is the reason for this. Perhaps have a rethink of exactly how you want this to work, and why.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson
Used jQuery migrate plugin to replace the jQuery code that is in the Bootstrap theme. I added: 
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js"></script>`

No worries! I understand! I'm doing an example now. Although it is working now, The console writes this message which say's it's not compatible with Quirks Mode. Not sure what that means.

`JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 3.0.0
jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js:62 JQMIGRATE: jQuery is not compatible with Quirks Mode
`

Comment: @allan No problem. If the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as accepted - thanks :-). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode has a good explanation of what quirks mode is. If you're running in quirks mode, then almost certainly you're using an outdated DOCTYPE declaration (or none at all). Unless you need to support a very old browser there should be no reason not to use the HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`)

Comment: @allan P.S. If you've added jquery.js then make sure you remove jquery slim as well, otherwise you could get odd conflicts. Also it might be better to use the minified (.min.js) version instead when you go live, because it's compressed, so will load faster, and once you're live it's less important to need to be able to read the source code for debugging anymore

Comment: Noted on all the points. I've added the minified so now it looks like this `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js` Appreciate the help!